# Stripped images in tween animation

Tags: android, image, animation, tween

Right after the last OS update for`Android (version 4.4.4... or it was 4.4.3?)`, my tween animations appear weird: sometimes images are showed with stripes when they are combined with a banner from any advertiser (admob, startapp...). It seems something related to `OpenGL` from banners, because when I disable the banner, tween animations are no more stripped.

It seems to be no difference if I use `Translate`, `Alpha`, `Rotate`... Sometimes it stripes the image, sometimes not.

How can I avoid this?

Note: all images (stripped and non stripped) are PNG with transparent background. I'm using a Motorola G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found it.

In your layer, go to the ImageView and add this:

android:layerType="software"

or

android:layerType="hardware"

And it works!

The solution was here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70914

Thank you, guys!